# What's the UV index on the Moon

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, radiation, moon

What would the UV index be on the moon compared to the Earth?
I'm pretty sure it would be ridiculously high but I'm not sure how high.

Comment: On the surface of the moon (in vacuum) I am at a loss to know what use the UV Index is to anyone.  If your skin is exposed to direct sunlight there, you have far more immediate problems to worry about than sunburn.

Comment: you can estimate this yourself: UV is a linear scale (time to damage $\propto$ power/area). You get a minimum factor of 4 (so UV=40+) for the definitional power density, and then some more for short wavelengths not seen down here. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultraviolet_index#Technical_definition